# Get list of keys in managed Redis | Google Cloud Memory Store

Tags: python, redis, google-cloud-memorystore

I'm working on Cloud Memory Store ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/)) for storing data in the Redis using [python client library](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/redis/index.html).

Python client library has various function to add, set, get, delete values ([for more info](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)), but I couldn't find anything to get the list of values that are already been stored in the database.

My use case is to fetch a chunk of keys(based on specific prefix) and delete them.

I want to know how to get the list of keys that are already stored in the database.

Comment: can you not just use the `keys` function to search for the pattern you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a python snippet using `scan()` to get all keys from the store matching a pattern and delete them one-by-one:

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
for key in r.keys('*'):
    # delete the key
    r.delete(key)
```

Comment: As of redis-py v3, StrictRedis is deprecated and is just `Redis`

Comment: And this does not use `scan()`... it uses `keys()`

Comment: oh i see, but i think it woks, isn’t it?

Comment: Should work, with the regular "do not use keys() in production" disclaimer/warning/best-practice/advice-to-live-by